Button don't recognize PrimitiveButtonStyle, and may not be available in the context
I'm currently learning about SwiftUI and somehow when using .buttonStyle at Button, the static properties like .bordered and .borderless can't be found in the Xcode autocomplete and if I force type it the error shows:

This static property is defined on PrimitiveButtonStyle, and may not be available in this context.

Do anyone know what is causing this? I can't find any discussion related to this issue.

I tried rewriting the code with different approach and also re-run Xcode.

Have you tried ignoring that and just compile the code anyway? The code itself works, right? This is just Xcode's autocomplete being dumb.

@Sweeper yes ignoring and force typing the code works, but I'm not sure it was a good things to do and I'm scared it might be causing crashing error in the future

Don't worry. This is just Xcode's fault, not related to your code.

You can ignore this error and type .bordered without using the autocomplete suggestions. After that, Xcode will successfully compile the code without errors, as expected.
Xcode is just confused here because there are two overloads of buttonStyle, having almost the same signature except different constraints on their parameter types. (1, 2)
func buttonStyle<S>(_ style: S) -> some View where S : PrimitiveButtonStyle
func buttonStyle<S>(_ style: S) -> some View where S : ButtonStyle

In this case, the autocomplete is unable to find the static members of both PrimitiveButtonStyle and ButtonStyle when you type ., and instead finds only the static members of ButtonStyle. Therefore, bordered and borderless etc are not in the autocomplete list. From my experimentation, it seems to favour the overload that is declared last.
We can reproduce this behaviour with a simple example like this:
protocol Foo {
    
}

protocol Bar {
    
}

extension Foo {
    static var foo: Foo { fatalError() }
}

extension Bar {
    static var bar: Bar { fatalError() }
}

func foo<T: Foo>(_ foo: T) {}
func foo<T: Bar>(_ foo: T) {}

foo(./* only bar is shown in the autocomplete here */)

If you really don't like to see the "error", you can wrap the existing buttonStyle modifier with a modifier of your own, that has a different name.
extension View {
    func buttonAppearance<S: PrimitiveButtonStyle>(_ s: S) -> some View {
        buttonStyle(s)
    }
}

Now typing .buttonAppearance(.) will give you the static members of PrimitiveButonStyle in the autocomplete list.
